# Smallest values for int8_t and int64_t

Tags: c++

With regard to to those definitions found in `stdint.h`, I wish to test a function for converting vectors of `int8_t` or vectors of `int64_t` to vectors of `std::string`.

Here are my tests:

```
TEST(TestAlgorithms, toStringForInt8)
{
    std::vector<int8_t> input = boost::assign::list_of(-128)(0)(127);
    Container container(input);
    EXPECT_TRUE(boost::apply_visitor(ToString(),container) == boost::assign::list_of("-128")("0")("127"));
}

TEST(TestAlgorithms, toStringForInt64)
{
    std::vector<int64_t> input = boost::assign::list_of(-9223372036854775808)(0)(9223372036854775807);
    Container container(input);
    EXPECT_TRUE(boost::apply_visitor(ToString(),container) == boost::assign::list_of("-9223372036854775808")("0")("9223372036854775807"));
}
```

However, I am getting a warning in visual studio for the line:

```
std::vector<int64_t> input = boost::assign::list_of(-9223372036854775808)(0)(9223372036854775807);
```

as follows:

```
warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
```

If I change -9223372036854775808 to -9223372036854775807, the warning disappears.

What is the issue here? With regard to my original code, the test is passing.

Comment: Did you also try -9223372036854775808ll? As Bo Persson suggested, you should use std:numeric_limits anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's like the compiler says, `-9223372036854775808` is not a valid number because the `-` and the digits are treated separately.

You could try  `-9223372036854775807 - 1` or use `std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min()` instead.

Comment: +1 for `std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min()`, which is the cleanest, most expressive, portable way to go.

Comment: @DevSolar It's certainly cleaner and more expressive.  With regards to portability, however: `int64_t` is required to be exactly 64 bits, 2's complement representation, which means that it will have exactly the same minimum value everywhere.

Comment: @JamesKanze: right, but `-9223372036854775808` is a non-portable way to write that minimum value (since on implementations with a 2's complement 64 bit `long long`, it invokes an implementation-defined unsigned->signed conversion) whereas `std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min()` is a portable way. I think `-9223372036854775807 - 1` is non-portable too, but only fails on a hypothetical system where `long long` is sign-magnitude (so the arithmetic overflows in a constant expression and is diagnosed), while `int64_t` is some extended 2's complement integer type.

Comment: @SteveJessop Good points.  Another portable way would be `UINT64_MIN` Which is also quite readable---in some cases, it could also have the avantage of being an integral const expression, although C++11 fixes that in `std::numeric_limits` as well (and integral const expression or not, I doubt that `int a[UINT64_MAX];` is going to work).

Comment: @JamesKanze: yes, personally I prefer the macros where it's possible to use them (so pretty much whenever the integer type isn't a template argument or deduced with `auto` / `decltype`). `INT64_MIN` etc also have the (dubious) advantage that you can use them in preprocessor expressions.

Comment: @SteveJessop I also prefer the macros, but... I suspect this is partially a question of habit---I've been using the macros for about 30 years.  On the other hand: if it ain't broken, why fix it.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that integer literals are not negative; so `-42` is not a literal with a negative value, but rather the `-` operator applied to the literal `42`.

In this case, `9223372036854775808` is out of the range of `int64_t`, so it will be given an unsigned type. Due to the magic of modular arithmetic, you can still negate it, assign it to `int64_t`, and end up with the result you expect; but the compiler will warn you about the unsigned negation (if you tell it to) since that can often be the result of an error.

You could avoid the warning (and make the code more obviously correct) by using `std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Change `-9223372036854775808` to `-9223372036854775807-1`.

The issue is that `-9223372036854775808` isn't `-9223372036854775808` but rather `-(9223372036854775808)` and `9223372036854775808` cannot fit into a signed 64-bit type (decimal integer constants by default are a signed type), so it instead becomes unsigned. Applying negation with `-` to an unsigned type is suspicious, hence the warning.